# Slideshow software for three screen setup

Tags: windows-7, photos, slideshow

I'd like to create a 10 minute slideshow for a party. At the party location, there are three side-by-side screens available and I'd like to take advantage of them. For example, I'd like a to show pictures of me with the same people when I was a baby, teenager and adult - one on each screen.

Is there software available that will do this? Am I better off limiting it to one screen?

Comment: Are the screens already connected to the same computer?

Comment: hi danny, what os?

Comment: All the screens are connected to the same computer. I'm using Windows 7.